Product of expectation of two random variables
If I know that $\operatorname{E}(X) \geq 0$ and $\operatorname{E}(Y) \geq 0$, can I say that $\operatorname{E}(XY) \geq 0$
I think yes but I am not sure of the proof (I would try conditionning one of the expectation with respect to $X$ or $Y$).
Thanks in advance.

This is not true.
Consider the following:
$$(X,Y)=\begin{cases} (1,-1)  & \text{with probability 0.5} \\ (-1,1) & \text{with probability 0.5}\end{cases}$$
We can easily see that $E(X)=E(Y)=0$ but $XY=-1$.

More generally, if $\mathbb{E}[X] = 0$ and $Y = -X$, then $\mathbb{E}[XY] = \mathbb{E}[-X^2] \le 0 $, which would require $X \equiv 0$ for the claim to be true. Therefore, any non-zero centred random variable $X$ gives a counterexample.

An obvious follow-up: what if we require $>0$ rather than $\geq 0$? (It's still not true but requires a little more effort to construct an example.)

Thank you for your answer. I will try to look at the case where $> 0$
